# Retrieving values from MySQL using php

Tags: php, mysql, database

Here i have made an MySQL which has the columns of  "id","name","username","email",age" . Where even i made the the PHP code to retrieve the data for the given id.

eg:if the user enter id=3 then it shows the datas corresponding to the id.

But now i want set multiple inputs so that user can type more than one id and it list the corresponding datas of the particular id.

My PHP Code:

```
<?php 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

    $id  = $_GET['id'];




    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='".$id."'";

    $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $result = array();

            while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

    array_push($result,array(
        "id"=>$res['id'],
        "name"=>$res['name'],
        "username"=>$res['username'],
        "email"=>$res['email'],
         "age"=>$res['age']
        )
    );
            }
    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

    mysqli_close($con);

}
```

Now this URL gives the perfect result:
"http://www.allwaysready.16mb.com/Sort.php?id=4"

Now how can i get the corresponding values for the multiple id's?

Comment: never going to work, since you never use `$id` in your query. `$work` is undefined.

Comment: i edited the question

Comment: and you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: So what have you tried. **SO is not a free coding service** This would required chnages to your HTML and you PHP and as we annot see your HTML this is **Way off topic**

Answer (score 1):

You can use array syntax to pass multiple IDs to your script and use MySQL's [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) to query against them all at once.

URL: http://www.allwaysready.16mb.com/Sort.php?id[]=4&id[]1&id[]=2

```
$ids = $_GET['id'];
$ids = array_map(function($id) {
    return (int) $id;
}, $ids);
$ids = implode(',', $ids);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE work IN($ids);
```

I cast the IDs to integers because your current code is wide open to SQL injection. You really should be using paramterized queries.

Comment: I get some error can u answer with the exact code plz

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'id' (T_STRING) in /home/u115908902/public_html/mysort.php on line 19

Comment: I just added a line of code that I overlooked. See if that resolves anything for you.

Comment: i have another question, in the URL we must use the '&' sign uh ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118250/discussion-between-william-willi-and-john-conde).

Comment: Yes, you must use & unless you do some javascript magic that automatically groups these ids together for you

Answer (score 0):

Use the "IN" condition:

If id is a number:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id IN (89, 25);
```

If id is a string, put the id's in quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id IN ('89N', '15B', '25E');
```

Rewrite your query in PHP to use the In Query condition, paying close attention to your column definition data types.  Strings must be quoted for example.